# How do I pierce the secret of the windmill for "The Girl Who Cried Wolf" tier 5?

Tags: the-secret-world

I am on tier 5 of "The Girl Who Cried Wolf" in The Secret World and I have taken the rune stones found by the Orochi but I am unable to progress with the quest further. The quest text says I need to "pierce the secret of the Windmill" which I thought was rather strange wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another of those quests that many assume is bugged, when in fact it's just not very obvious.

Piercing actually has nothing to do with it. After looking around for a lot longer than expected we found it - at the base of the Windmill there is a door leading inside, on the door frame there are two spaces to place the runes which will open up a secret instance for further investigation.

Screenshot:

[image: Piercing indeed]